# Can I say I've worked with a client's client?

Tags: clients, portfolio

Let's say I build software for **Company A**.

**Company A** then licenses this software out to **Company B** and **Company C**.

I have no NDAs in place. **Companies B and C** both know that I built this software.

Occasionally, I might send and receive emails from someone working at **Company C** to support their use of the software (answering questions, adding features, etc.).

To what capacity can I say I've "worked with" **Companies B and C**?

For example, would it be misrepresentative to put that I have worked with **Company C** on a portfolio or resume?

I doubt there would be any legal repercussions, but just in case, I live and work in the UK and the software is hosted on UK-based servers.

Comment: Wouldnt do that if I were you, because I would not like if my advisor/builder would have their employees mention me on their resume.
Unless you can make it really clear that you worked for them as a Client of Company A

Comment: You should only put companies you work directly for on your resume or portfolio (if you're a consultant, you *may* be able to say "while working for A, I was assigned to projects at B & C"). In your situation though, if someone asks about companies B & C, you can say that you're familiar with them.

Comment: It is unclear if you are still working for Company A.  If you are then I would say that working with C comes under the heading of providing support for customers of A.   If you aren't working for A are you receiving any consulting fees from C for providing ongoing support?

Comment: Does company A license this same software to other companies?  Approximately how many?

Comment: "To what capacity can I say I've "worked with" Companies B and C?" - other than saying you occasionally sent and received emails from C, you cannot honestly say you have worked with them. You haven't. I can't say I've "worked with Microsoft" just because I use Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not work for Company B or C

I guess you could say worked with but a few emails in support of the software is pretty minor.

To me it would need to be a multi month full time engagement to list the name of the customer and then be clear you were not a direct employee.

Comment: This seems to be the consensus. What if – when listing the work on my portfolio, for example – I put something like, "I built this for Company A who provide services for Company B and Company C"?

Comment: If you want to list the software you wrote was used by Company C and Company C and you provided software support to me that is fair and truthful statement.  As long as Company A does not consider that confidential information.  You still want to use A as a reference so avoid something that would piss them. off.

Comment: I would run this all by Company A first. They are very amicable. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Sanaco does telling prospective employers which clients Company A serves do anything to improve *your* resume? In most cases, it probably doesn't. Prospective employers don't care much who your company provides services to unless they're a **very** large, **very** high-profile company

Comment: @alroc that's a very valid question. I would say "maybe" to the point it wouldn't hurt by putting it on, it could only help (or not make any difference). There are a few very large and high profile global companies across a broad range of disciplines and industries (for example clothing, legal, and real-estate).

Answer (score 2):

You could say something like I supported Company B & C through Company A during the implementation and ongoing support of product/system_name_here, which gives you credit of what transpired to a certain extent but putting something like you worked with companies B & C would not be truthful. And should your prospective employer wants to check your credentials with companies B & C, it might backfire for you.

Answer (score 1):

If it was a **dedicated** role to support these other companies directly through Company A, I would list it as:

> Company A (MM/YY - MM/YY)
>   (For Company B MM/YY - MM/YY)
>   (For Company C MM/YY - MM/YY)

If you were on-site at these locations:

> Company A (MM/YY - MM/YY)
>   (At Company B MM/YY - MM/YY)

If it was **not** a dedicated role to support these clients, I would leave it off. It is not uncommon for support personnel at a company to work with various clients, and it would be deceiving to claim any working knowledge with them in a support role unless your role was dedicated to that client.

Comment: Hmm. This is something I can consider for other projects where exactly this would apply, but for the one in question, no - I was not in a dedicated support role. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does all your software for Company A go either to Company B or C? If it does then you are in a way a contractor for companies B/C through company A. A line item on your resume might look like: Software Developer for ABC Employment *Contracted to Big Company B / Big Company C*

You can look up further examples of how contractors list their positions.

If Companies B/C only make up some of who uses your software but not all of it, and your current employer provides other services to B & C or support your work in other ways, it might be more appropriate to list them in your responsibilities.

- Developed XYZ Project for Company B.

Then go on in more detail on the project. Include that you supported those companies. Demonstrating your support to clients of your current company is never a bad thing. Especially if Company B / C represent a particular industry niche that it might be useful to advertise you have experience in.

Answer (score 0):

Your **client's client** is known as your **End Client**.

In the situation described above, Company B and Company C would both be defined as an end client.

If you work extensively with an end client for weeks or months at a time, then it is fair to list them as they pertain to a particular project, beneath your client:

> **Company A** (MM/YY - MM/YY)
>
> - Developed code for **Company B** (MM/YY - MM/YY)
> - Designed staging server for **Company C** (MM/YY - MM/YY)

However, since neither Company A nor Company B are your direct clients, you cannot list them as such.